# Could הָעַלְמָ֗ה in Isaiah 7:14, be a reference to Zion?

Tags: messiah, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

**According to John R. W. Stott (NT),"The Message of Isaiah", הָעַלְמָ֗ה in Isaiah 7:14, is a symbol for Zion:**

*In chapter 7 we see him doing this to Ahaz. Ahaz has rejected the clear word of
the prophet (7-9) and the offer of a clear sign to confirm it (10-12). Therefore he
is given a sign which is veiled and enigmatic, a sign which he cannot understand
(13-16).
But the sign is not meaningless. It can be understood, but only from the
perspective of faith, and again chapter 6 provides the key. The final verse of that
chapter spoke of a righteous remnant, a ‘holy seed’, that would survive the
coming judgment. At the beginning of chapter 7 Isaiah is pointedly told to take
his son Shear-Jashub with him as he goes to meet Ahaz (3). ‘Shear-Jashub’
means ‘a remnant shall return’ or ‘a remnant shall repent’. Both are possible,
99
but since the immediate context here is one of faith versus unbelief rather than
exile and return, the latter meaning is almost certainly the primary one.
100 Isaiah
comes to challenge Ahaz to repent and join the remnant who believe, but he
refuses. The Immanuel saying of verse 14 is therefore given to Ahaz as a veiled
message of judgment.
Zion has already been pictured as a woman (literally, ‘daughter Zion’) in
1:8. Now, in the crisis of invasion and imminent siege, she is depicted as a
sexually mature woman (literally, ‘young woman’, ‘almâ) who has already
conceived and is even now in the pains of childbirth. The central statement of
verse 14 is literally: ‘The young woman has conceived and is giving birth to a
son…’ If the ‘young woman’ is Zion, then her son is the faithful remnant who
will emerge from her sufferings.
101 That is why he is given the name Immanuel,
‘God with us’. God will be with the faithful remnant who gather round Isaiah (cf
8:16), not with the unbelieving Ahaz and the rebellious nation as a whole. This is
the implication of the ominous shift from ‘your God’ in verse 11 to my God in
verse 13.The rest of the chapter unfolds in explicit terms the threat implied in the
Immanuel saying. The image of the ‘son’ or child, however, continues only to
the end of verse 16.
102 By the time this child has reached an age of accountability
(within a few years at the most), the land will have been so devastated and
depopulated by Assyria that cultivation will be impossible; the survivors will
have to exist on the products of the few animals they have and any wild food
they can gather (15a, 17-25). But even before this (16a), the land of the two
kings presently invading Judah will be deserted. In fact, Syria fell to the
Assyrians in 732 BC ,
103 followed by Israel in 722
BC .
104 Finally, Judah herself
was all but devastated in 701 BC .
105
But the Immanuel sign contained a promise as well as a threat. For Isaiah
and his followers it meant the promise of God’s protecting presence and the
eventual fulfilment of God’s good purposes for his people. The preservation of
the remnant in Isaiah’s day was part of a process which led finally to the coming
of Jesus, the perfectly faithful and righteous one,
106 in whom all God’s promises
come to fulfilment.
107 So Matthew was right to see the ultimate fulfilment of the
Immanuel saying in Jesus Christ.
108 What was death to Ahaz is life to us who
believe.*

**Does his interpretation make any sense?**

Comment: No it does not. The correct translation is "the young woman" meaning he is pointing to a specific woman that he is pointing to. He is saying that she is currently pregnant and will soon give birth.

Comment: @sabbahillel Important to also note the context of the entire passage in the Navi isn't at all Messianic in nature

Comment: @ezra yes I know I just answered the final question in his post showing that the basic text shows that it is totally against what he says

Answer (score 2):

John R. W. Stott completely disregards Isaiah 7:16, literally two verses later:

> 16 חֶמְאָ֥ה וּדְבַ֖שׁ יֹאכֵ֑ל לְדַעְתּ֛וֹ מָא֥וֹס בָּרָ֖ע וּבָח֥וֹר בַּטּֽוֹב 
> For, when the lad does not yet know to reject bad and choose good, the land whose two kings you dread, shall be abandoned."

Where the *actual* proof is that the before the child has even gotten old enough to know good from bad the two kings will have already been defeated (rather than the woman being pregnant), which is a clear discussion grounded in something that Ahaz can see. Instead, John R. W. Stott invents his own story and bases his entire proof of Jesus on that:

> ...the land will have been so devastated and depopulated by Assyria that cultivation will be impossible...

I would say that this is nonsensical Christian apologetics trying to make sense of a mangled interpretation in order to justify their own mistaken beliefs rather than anything resembling a scholarly analysis of the verse.

Ultimately, if a "holy book" completely contradicts itself by butchering its own proof-texts and lying to you about their translation and context, you need to ask yourself: is this really a "holy" book at all?